WCF endpoint behaviors not getting called after CustomUserNamePasswordValidator throws exception
Running into an issue where our EndpointBehaviors are not running when an exception is thrown from our WebServiceHost which registers a CustomUserNamePasswordValidator
host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNamePasswordValidator();

We programmatically add the ServiceEndpoint to the host, which adds Behaviors to handle CORS support and some custom error handling. From our UserNamePasswordValidator we throw an exception if the credentials fail, and the client is receiving the correct status code HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.
The problem is that in this case, it doesn't appear that any of our endpoint behaviors are being called. For instance, we have a IDispatchMessageInspector which is not having it's AfterReceiveRequest or BeforeSendReply called.
We also have a behavior which adds a ErrorHandler, via:
endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new HTTPBindingErrorHandler());

And the HTTPBindingErrorHandler doesn't have it's IErrorHandler methods called when our custom usernamepassword validator throws an exception.
Does anyone understand why this would happen? Are there alternatives to handling Basic auth in a WebServiceHost that will play nicely with endpoint behaviors?

I have a suggestion that you can refer to:
My approach is to create a CustomUserNamePasswordValidator (which requires a certificate).
Such as:
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
 {
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    if (null == userName || null == password)
    {
            //your behavior
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (userName != "admin" && password != "wcf.admin") 
        {
       //your behavior
        throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
       

    }

}

}

In this way, the clearance judgment will be performed before the outlier is thrown. However, these operations cannot be placed after an exception has been thrown.

That is what Im doing. The issue is that when an exception is thrown from Validate, no other handlers are called. We implement CORS using endpoint  message dispatch, but it fails to add the CORS headers if validate fails.

I mean when you use throw new ArgumentNullException() in your C# code; , it means that you actively threw an exception. Throwing an exception immediately stops the execution of the current method, and any subsequent code will not be executed unless the exception is caught somewhere in the call stack (try-catch).
